# Why references to nuget packages left in app.config after uninstall?

Tags: nuget, app-config

I had Common.Logging package installed by mistake in my VS2017 project.

Ok, I uninstalled it.

But when I checked App.config I still see it there:

[image]

Why references to nuget packages left in app.config after uninstall?

Comment: Not a solution, but I hope this helps - There is a known bug that you can follow - https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6870